# Strip an ordered sequence of characters from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, strip

I've realized recently that the `strip` builtin of Python (and it's children `rstrip` and `lstrip`) does not treat the string that is given to it as argument as an ordered sequence of chars, but instead as a kind of "reservoir" of chars:

```
>>> s = 'abcfooabc'
>>> s.strip('abc')
'foo'
>>> s.strip('cba')
'foo'
>>> s.strip('acb')
'foo'
```

and so on.

Is there a way to strip an *ordered* substring from a given string, so that the output would be different in the above examples ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of a built-in way, no, but it's pretty simple:

```
def strip_string(string, to_strip):
    if to_strip:
        while string.startswith(to_strip):
            string = string[len(to_strip):]
        while string.endswith(to_strip):
            string = string[:-len(to_strip)]
    return string
```

Comment: What if the substring is in the middle?

Comment: @ecline6: Then it will behave in the expected way, not removing it.

Answer (score 11):

I had this same problem when I first started.

Try [str.replace](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) instead?

```
>>> s = 'abcfooabc'
>>> s.replace("abc", "")
0: 'foo'
>>> s.replace("cba", "")
1: 'abcfooabc'
>>> s.replace("acb", "")
2: 'abcfooabc'
```

Comment: OP seems to be confused about the difference between strip and replace.  What would be expected output for `"fooabcfoo"`?

Answer (score 8):

As of Python 3.9 you can use [str.removeprefix](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix) and [str.removesuffix](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix).

From the docs:

```
'TestHook'.removeprefix('Test')  # >> 'Hook'
'MiscTests'.removesuffix('Tests')  # >> 'Misc'
```

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised `re.sub` wasn't mentioned yet:

```
>>> re.sub("^abc", "", "abcfooabc") # ^ regex operator matches the beginning of a string
'fooabc'
>>> re.sub("^abc|abc$", "", "abcfooabc") # | string begins with abc or (|) ends with abc
'foo'
>>> re.sub("abc$", "", "abcfooabc") # | string begins with abc or (|) ends with abc
'abcfoo'
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:
`s.split('abc')`.

That returns: `['', 'foo', '']`.

So, we can change it to:

`[i for i in s.split('abc') if i != '']`. If you only want `'foo'`, and not `['foo']`, you can do: `[i for i in s.split('abc') if i != ''][0]`.

All together:

```
def splitString(s, delimiter):
    return [i for i in s.split(delimiter) if i != ''][0]
```

Comment: I think it breaks for a case like `"abcfooabcfooabc"`

Comment: @wim `''.join(i for i in s.split(delimiter) if i)`

Comment: @sapi that doesn't put the delimiter back into the middle

Comment: My mistake, I was also confused with the OP's strip / replace thing.  You could put the middle ones back in with something like `''.join(ss or d for (i,ss) in enumerate(s.split(d)) if ss or not i or i == len(s) - 1)`, but that starts to get a little ugly to read.